# Чтение из текстового файла в QTableView

Tags: c++, qt5, c++11

Требуется из простого текстового файла выгрузить данные построчно в `QTableView` (используется `QStandardItemModel`). Все интересующие меня данные я получаю правильно - одно значение на одну строку, тут никаких проблем. Таблица имеет 5 столбцов и неограниченное количество строк.

Вопрос, собственно, в том, как складывать по 5 строк из файла в одну строку таблицы?

Пока все данные грузятся в первый столбец, количество строк - как в текстовом файле...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну например вот так:

```
//допустим, что у вас уже считаны пять строк из файла (например в QStringList columns)
QList<QStandardItem*> newRow;
for (auto columnText:columns)
{
    auto newItem = new QStandardItem(columnText);
    newRow.append(newItem);
}
model.appendRow(newRow);
```

Если без лишних изысков объединить этот вариант и ваш пример из комментариев, то можно получить что-нибудь такое:

```
int columnIndex = 0;
QRegularExpression re("(.+)="); 
QStringList columns;
QTextStream in(&file); 
while(!in.atEnd()) 
{ 
    auto readLine = in.readLine().split(re, QString::SkipEmptyParts); 
    if (!readLine.isEmpty())
    {
        columns.append(readLine.at(0));
        ++columnIndex;

        if (columnIndex == 5)
        {
            QList<QStandardItem*> newRow;
            for (auto columnText:columns)
            {
                auto newItem = new QStandardItem(columnText);
                newRow.append(newItem);
            }
            model.appendRow(newRow);
            columns.clear();
            columnIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, весь код в комментарий не помещается.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что в таком виде он не очень читаем? )

Comment: Пытаюсь вставить как код, что-то не очень получается, возможно потому что из линукса.

Comment: QTextStream in(&file);
int lineIndex(0);
   while(!in.atEnd())
      {
      QRegularExpression re("(.+)=");
      QStringList readLine = in.readLine().split(re, QString::SkipEmptyParts);
         for (int col = 0; col < readLine.size(); col++)
         {
         QString value = readLine.at(col);
         QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(value);
         model->setItem(lineIndex, col, item);
         }
    lineIndex++;
      }

Не получается что-то форматированный код вставить, не знаю, почему.

Comment: Ну.. если я правильно понял формат входных данных, то readLine у вас каждый раз состоит из одного элемента.

Comment: Да - один элемент на строку в файле. Просто нужно прочитать 5 строк из файла и записать в одну строку таблицы (т.е. распределить по 5 колонкам).

Comment: В файле записи вида int a=value, я беру только значения после знака равно по регулярному выражению.

Comment: Добавил в ответ код, который у меня получился из вашего и моего примеров. Я его не проверял, но вроде должно работать)

Comment: Великолепно! Все работает просто отлично. Спасибо большое ))